# What type of programming languages and tools do we need to develop windows desktop application?

Tags: desktop-application

I am a web based developer and now I am ready to move into desktop application development, therefore I need someone to help me on the below questions.

1. What type of tool are you people using to develop windows desktop, silverlight is the one?
2. What type of programming languages are you people using to develop desktop app, C++ is the one?
3. what else besides c++, Visual Basic is the one?
4. how to integrate silverlight with above mentioned languages?
5. can we use .NET as well?

Comment: .net is the framework used for MS. So that would include things like VB, C# etc..

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different options for developing Windows apps, here are what I think are the most common options.  Note you can either go the .NET route, or you can go the C++ route, but if you're just starting off, I think .NET will be a much easier initial learning curve.

- IDE: Visual Studio 2010 - you can buy this, or download the Express version for free.
- Frameworks: .NET Framework
- Programming Languages (for .NET): C# or VB.NET
- Windows Apps technologies:  WPF or Windows Forms (Silverlight is a "subset" of WPF, with some more specific intended use scenarios).

For the IDE, Visual Studio is definitely the way to go.  You can also use other tools such as Mono/Mono Develop or just the command line tools and a text editor, but Visual Studio has a lot of benefits.  For starting off in Windows apps, I'd recommend the .NET route (C#/VB.NET) over C++, unless you're an expert in C++ already.  If you know C, C++, or Java, C# is similar in syntax, but if you know VB, you might like VB.NET.  I personally prefer C# over VB.NET.  For the Windows apps technologies, WPF is the latest and greatest technology from Microsoft, but Windows Forms is still a decent choice, and will be around for a long time.  If you have experience in VB, you might find Windows Forms to be more familiar, but WPF has a lot of really powerful features that might be worth reading about.  WPF is probably considered more on the "cutting edge" as opposed to the more mature Windows Forms.  As far as Silverlight, there are ways to deploy a Silverlight app on the desktop, but WPF is probably the more recommended route for desktop apps.  Silverlight tends to have more specific uses, such as Windows Phone or rich web-based apps.

There are a million other options, but these are probably a good starting point.

Comment: I first thought perhaps you meant the Win32 / Win64 / MFC route rather than the C++ route. These APIs can be used by most programming languages - Win32 certainly was originally developed for C rather than C++, and both Visual Basic and Delphi (Pascal) were once mainstream languages that targeted those APIs. No Silverlight, though. But perhaps you're emphasizing the fact that although Managed C++ works with .NET, it's kind of between worlds, and not .NET focussed in the way that C# is.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really go into the C++ options, I'm obviously slanted more towards the pure .NET stuff for starting off.

Comment: makes sense. All that worry about GC vs. non-GC and so on for managed C++, getting the interaction between standard C++ and .NET stuff to work - you're right, not for beginners. Standard C++ is complex already, let alone including the more-than-slightly-mismatched managed C++ and .NET stuff.

Comment: Hi, I think I will use c#, can we run c# and xaml on silverlight without using visual studio?